Can 逆恨みされる mean 逆恨みを受ける?
From the recent Oshi no ko chapter (Spoiler warning):

For context, Aqua and Kamiki jumped into an ocean together, drowning both of them in the process. News fabricated the story a bit and said that Aqua was killed by Kamiki. In case if anyone doesn't know the story, Aqua resented Kamiki for a long time.
I am not sure about the meaning of 逆恨み. When I look up the meaning of 逆恨み in Meikyou, I get:

さか‐うらみ【逆恨み】〘名・他サ変〙
❶ 恨みに思う人から逆に恨まれること。また、その恨み。
❷ 人の好意を悪くとって、逆に恨むこと。「助言をしたら━された」
❸ 〔俗〕筋違いなことを理由に恨むこと。「解雇を━して放火する」◇近年の言い方。

Based on context, I think I can ignore ❷ and ❸, which leaves us with ❶. However, I am not sure if 逆恨み in 逆恨みされる can be used in this sense because I think it is often paired with 受ける: 逆恨みを受ける.

From the context, it is reasonable for Aqua to have grudge against Kamiki, and thus, people, who suppose that Kamiki killed Aqua, think the grudge of Kamiki against Aqua is 逆 “opposite” in the sense of ❶.
逆恨みされる in the sense of passive is totally fine as well as 逆恨みを受ける.
